# How to move files with firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Is there a way to move files with firebase.storage()?

Example:
user1/public/image.jpg to user1/private/image.jpg

Comment: See "Renaming, copying, and moving objects" here:https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no such way to move to other location, rather you can download and then put it to other reference and deleting the previous location.

Answer (score 19):

Since Firebase Storage is backed by Google Cloud Storage, you can use GCS's `rewrite` API ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite)) or `gsutil mv` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv)).

Also, an example of `move` ([docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#move)) in GCloud Node follows:

```
var bucket = gcs.bucket('my-bucket');
var file = bucket.file('my-image.png');
var newLocation = 'gs://another-bucket/my-image-new.png';
file.move(newLocation, function(err, destinationFile, apiResponse) {
  // `my-bucket` no longer contains:
  // - "my-image.png"
  //
  // `another-bucket` now contains:
  // - "my-image-new.png"

  // `destinationFile` is an instance of a File object that refers to your
  // new file.
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this solution combined with the firebase's storage rules?

Comment: Currently no, but in the future we may allow service accounts to be subjected to the same rules that third party authenticated users are.

Answer (score 10):

As of March 29, 2022 it is possible to call the "move" function directly in this way:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import {getStorage} from "firebase-admin/storage";

export const triggerStorage = functions
  .storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const bucket = getStorage().bucket(object.bucket);
    const destPath = "user1/private/image.jpg";
    await bucket.file(object.name).move(destPath);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a JavaScript function that accomplishes this using only the firebase storage API.

Happy Coding!

```
/**
 * Moves a file in firebase storage from its current location to the destination
 * returns the status object for the moved file.
 * @param {String} currentPath The path to the existing file from storage root
 * @param {String} destinationPath The desired pathe for the existing file after storage
 */
function moveFirebaseFile(currentPath, destinationPath) {
    let oldRef = storage.ref().child(currentPath)

    oldRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        fetch(url).then(htmlReturn => {
            let fileArray = new Uint8Array()
            const reader = htmlReturn.body.getReader()

            //get the reader that reads the readable stream of data
            reader
                .read()
                .then(function appendStreamChunk({ done, value }) {
                    //If the reader doesn't return "done = true" append the chunk that was returned to us
                    // rinse and repeat until it is done.
                    if (value) {
                        fileArray = mergeTypedArrays(fileArray, value)
                    }
                    if (done) {
                        console.log(fileArray)
                        return fileArray
                    } else {
                        // "Readout not complete, reading next chunk"
                        return reader.read().then(appendStreamChunk)
                    }
                })
                .then(file => {
                    //Write the file to the new storage place
                    let status = storage
                        .ref()
                        .child(destinationPath)
                        .put(file)
                    //Remove the old reference
                    oldRef.delete()

                    return status
                })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: @newswiftcoder yes, it is. it uses ES6 syntax (arrow functions, `fetch`, object destructuring, etc.)

Comment: So it is like downloading and uploading. Same idea. I wished there is some API that does that without downloading the files (either locally or via cloud functions).

Comment: mergeTypedArrays isn't found. Is this defined in a package somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might stumble upon when using the other answers -
when downloading the file it will have the file name of the old, copied file.

To fix that issue you need to change the **contentDisposition** metadata of the file.

```
let metadata = {
        // Here predefined key/value
        contentDisposition: "inline; filename=yourfilename.txt",

        metadata: {
          // Not here! custom key/value
        },
      };
```

To see the full predefined metadata properties:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata

Answer (score 0):

In **Google Cloud Console** > **Cloud Storage** > **Bucket** > **yourapp.appspot.com**  > **Transfer Data IN/OUT** (Options: Choose a source > Filter by Prefix > Exclude/Include file/folder to be moved, for example if you want to move all the files from the bucket in the folder Users, you want to exclude the folder "Users/")

You can also opt in for the data to be deleted after move in Choose Settings

Click **Create** and its done, it will take a few minutes if you have alot of files