# Rename file in Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have read that because of some security reasons I'm not able to rename a file in Javascript. But is there a way of renaming it on firebase?

Thanks

Comment: There is no API in Firebase Storage to rename files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601548/how-to-move-files-with-firebase-storage/38604014#38604014

Comment: Ok, then I will take a diffrent approche. Thanks though!