# Rename or Download File from Firebase Storage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, xmlhttprequest, blob, firebase-storage

Is there any way to rename or download the file from the firebase storage?

I don't see the rename method nor download method.

I tried to download the file by the url and it doesn't work at all

```
var blob = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("GET", "downloadURL"); 
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function() 
{
    blob = xhr.response;//xhr.response is now a blob object
    console.log(blob);
}
xhr.send();
```

It returns

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: There is no built-in API to rename/move files on Firebase Storage. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601548/how-to-move-files-with-firebase-storage

Answer (score 2):

Two things here:

1) you want to use the `getDownloadURL()` method ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files)) to get a public download URL, that way you can simply drop your item in an `<img>` tag, allow users to click on it to download it, or use an `XMLHttpRequest` to get the bytes.

2) you'll want to enable CORS on your objects, see: [Firebase Storage and Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

Trigger click with javascript...

```
<a href="downloadURL" download="filename.txt">download filename.txt</a>
```

Comment: I may not be clear enough. What I mean is to download the file as a file variable like blob in javascript

Comment: With this the file will be renamed to filename.txt

Comment: But now when it's more clear what you want... You should try to get [CORS enable](http://enable-cors.org/) if you can. Otherwise you need something like a [CORS proxy](https://www.google.com/search?q=CORS%20proxy&rct=j)