# How can I copy the contents of a firebase storage bucket from one project to another?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase storage to store profile pictures. I've created two projects: MyApp and MyApp-Dev. I can easily download the json data from the MyApp database and upload it to MyApp-Dev database. Is there a way to do something similar to transfer the images from one project to another? Without the user's profile pictures it makes testing MyApp-Dev quite difficult.

Comment: Possibly relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601548/how-to-move-files-with-firebase-storage

Answer (score 13):

If you have the Google Cloud SDK installed you can use the **gsutil** command.

[Install GCP SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install)

[gsutil doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)

And you could move the information between buckets. Example:

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://<bucket-myapp-name> gs://<bucket-myapp-dev-name>
```

**-m** to run in parallel. This can significantly improve
              performance if you are performing operations on a large number of
              files over a reasonably fast network connection

**cp** copy

**-r** recursive

Comment: Using the command provided the copied files ended up in bucket B in a directory named after bucket A. Any way to get the files from bucket A to be stored in the root of bucket B so both buckets have the same exact structure?

Comment: You can run this command in web terminal. Docs: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/starting-cloud-shell

Use /* after bucket name to get the same structure. 
Like:  gsutil -m cp -r gs://<bucket-myapp-name>/* gs://<bucket-myapp-dev-name>

Answer (score 12):

I did copy bucket A to be stored in the root of bucket B,

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://<bucket-a>/* gs://<bucket-B>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly..! This should be the selected answer