# Rename files in firebase storage in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to rename files in my firebase storage from my android codes. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38604014/7644045 here say there is no way to do that.Are there any way to do without reupload all files? Because it affects performance too bad.For ex. I have a files 1-100.jpg and want to delete number 2.jpg and all numbers afterwards of 2 should be aligned.How can i do that?Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your question different from the one you linked? Why shouldn't this question be closed as a duplicate of that?

Comment: Sir it past 2 years from that.In 2 years changed everything.Is it abnormal to ask again? I just want help from ppl that have  same issue.   Maybe someone did the trick and can help me.

Comment: Nothing changed to this part: there is no API to rename files in the Firebase Storage SDK. As Mike's answer shows, you can rename files using the GCS SDK, for use on trusted environments, such as a server you control or Cloud Functions.