# How to copy an entire folder in firebase storage to a different location within firebase storage using node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage

Right now I can copy a single file to a different location but is there a way to copy the entire contents of a folder to a different location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move files with firebase storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601548/how-to-move-files-with-firebase-storage)

Answer (score 0):

In firebase-storage there is no concept of folder. There's the concept of `reference` e.g. "images/mountains.png" which you may have misinterpreted it as folder.

In order to copy all the content of similar references, you need to list all the files, then move the desire list of files over to new reference e.g. "archive/mountains.png"

This post may be useful
[How to get a list of all files in Cloud Storage in a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app/56402109#56402109)